# Entity Framework Codefirst and ASP.NET Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership, entity-framework-4.1

Does anybody have an example of how to properly reference a user in an ASP.NET membership table (users) in an entity using Entity Framework CodeFirst? I want the resulting table from CodeFirst to reference the existing ASP.NET membership tables. I can elaborate more if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm answering your question. But I use the "UserId" field of the "aspnet_Users" table in ForeignKey constraints to reference users.

Comment: So with CodeFirst you put the foreign key in after the database is created?

Comment: I'm not sure how you create foreign keys with CodeFirst, sorry. I always design my databases with NaviCat and then update the schema.

Answer (score 1):

I recently built a membership provider specifically for code-first development, I based it on the Altairis code-first example but mine has the ability to sit neatly in a separate library away from project code if the need arises.

Check it out at: http://cfmembershipprovider.codeplex.com